# Why Linux server is responding with TCP packets larger than MSS requested by client

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel

I am seeing a strange thing which is not what I expect as per the TCP theory:

The client while doing a handshake sets a MSS (Maximum Segment Size) of 1360 and a window size of 64K but the Linux server is sending TCP packets containing either 4KB, 7KB, some packets of 8KB which is more than 1360 and I expected it to be less than 1360 bytes.

I observed this by doing a `tcpdump` and then inspecting it in Wireshark.

I did not expect the server to send more than 1360 bytes per TCP packet. Am I wrong somewhere in my theoretical understanding of the workings of TCP?

Comment: The terminology here is very confused. There is no such thing as a 'TCP packet'. There are IP packets, and TCP segments. Which is it?

Comment: It is also answered in this similar question: [Why I get packet which data size larger than mss?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17229265/320437)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all as @fernacolo stated don't confuse MSS and MTU.

Maybe generic-segmentation-offload of your interface is on - read [here](http://rtoodtoo.net/2011/08/16/generic_segmentation_offload_and_wireshark/) for more info.

Comment: Link-only answer. To add useful information: See the offload setting: `ethtool -k eth0`, Disable offload: `ethtool -K eth0 tso off`

Answer (score 2):

If you are capturing packets on the server then you might see TCP sending out larger segments than the MTU. The packets on the wire, however, will be MTU size only. You can verify this by capturing on a network device (switch) etc. Alternatively, capturing packets on the remote (client) machine will reveal that each packet is <= MTU .

This behaviour is due to the fact that with TSO/GSO enabled, the TCP segment is split into MTU sized packets by the NIC hardware. Since `tcpdump` captures at the software layer, it sees segments larger than the MTU being sent to the NIC card for further transfer.

If you disable TSO/GSO for the NIC, then you will see all outgoing packets to be <= MTU size (more likely pMTU size).

Comment: TSO = TCP segmentation offload, GSO = generic segmentation offload, both can be set using `ethtool`. See the comment on the other answer.

Comment: The question was about [MSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size), not MTU.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you are confusing MSS with MTU. The packet size is limited by MTU, not by MSS. A full TCP packet contains MAC header, IP header, TCP header, TCP options and payload. So, a TCP packet can well be greater than MSS.

Comment: Yes, IP packet can be **40 bytes larger** than MSS. The segment must be made smaller by IP and TCP options. --- The OP wrote "TCP packet" instead of "TCP segment" but your "answer" should have rather been a comment.