# Why I get packet where data size is larger than MSS?

Tags: linux, tcp

I modified MTU with `ifconfig ethX mtu 300` on both PCs and tested the network with `netperf`.

I sniffed MSS=260 in the SYN packet with Wireshark but I got some data in packets larger than 260, why?

Comment: answer is here:
http://rtoodtoo.net/2011/08/16/generic_segmentation_offload_and_wireshark/

Comment: Similar question: [Why Linux Server is responding with TCP packets more than MSS requested by Client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7995876/320437)

Comment: @MatthiasBraun the updated link https://rtodto.net/generic_segmentation_offload_and_wireshark/ in the answer below is still functional.

Answer (score 1):

Sniffers capture packets between the kernel and the device driver. If the driver makes additional changes to the packets, you capture something different than the packets on the wire.

This is the case of TCP segmentation offload where the driver or the hardware device splits (or combines) the packet to obey the correct TCP MSS (maximum segment size).

You can (temporarily) disable the offload to see the correct segments:

- `ethtool -k eth0` --- see the settings
- `ethtool -K eth0 tso off` --- disable `tcp-segmentation-offload`

The information comes from the article linked in the question's comment: https://rtodto.net/generic_segmentation_offload_and_wireshark/

On Linux this offload also happens on the loopback interface!